# Extract "This story was generated," company name, date, time (.txt) and save the output into csv in python 2.7

Tags: python

### Hi can anyone provide me the code for python to extract company name date, and time in the text file and save the output into csv? The sample format (.txt) is as follows

**General Mills** tops 2Q profit forecasts

173 words

**17 December 2014
07:25 AM**

Associated Press Newswires

APRS

English

(c) 2014.  The Associated Press.  All Rights Reserved.

MINNEAPOLIS (AP) ? General Mills Inc. (GIS) on Wednesday reported earnings of $346.1 million in its fiscal second quarter.

The Minneapolis-based company said it had profit of 56 cents per share. Earnings, adjusted for restructuring costs, were 80 cents per share.

The results beat Wall Street expectations. The average estimate of analysts surveyed by Zacks Investment Research was for earnings of 76 cents per share.

The maker of Cheerios cereal, Yoplait yogurt and other packaged foods posted revenue of $4.71 billion in the period, falling short of Street forecasts. Analysts expected $4.84 billion, according to Zacks.

General Mills shares have risen slightly more than 2 percent since the beginning of the year, while the Standard & Poor's 500 index has increased almost 7 percent. The stock has risen slightly more than 2 percent in the last 12 months.

**This story was generated** by Automated Insights using data from Zacks Investment Research. GIS stock research report from Zacks.

Keywords:**General Mills**,Earnings Report

---

I used the following code to extract date and time

```
import os,csv,datefinder,datetime

os.chdir('C:\Users\dul\Desktop\Article')


with open("test2.txt", 'r') as file1:
  text1=file1.read()

matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(text1))

if len(matches) > 0:
date=matches[1]
print date
else:
print 'No dates found'
```

But I do not know how to capture "This story was generate" and company name....Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Which company, General Mills or Associated Press?

Comment: @mVChr General Mills. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can pull the first item in `Keywords`.

```
import re
re.search(r'Keywords:([^,]*)(,|$)', text1).group(1).strip()
```

Comment: Can you help me save to csv? three columns of "comany | date | time"?

Comment: Also how to capture "this story was generated" @mCVhr

Comment: That's not what this site is for.